# Python Scope within Classes

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I'm writing this class to normalize data in an array. self.x gets overwritten when I use the norm function on self.x to return a normalized matrix.

Not sure why self.x matrix is getting overwritten :

```
class normData():

    def __init__(self, file):
        self.file = file
        self.data = self.readtxt()
        self.x = self.data[:,0:-1]
        self.y = self.data[:,-1]
        # self.y_norm = self.norm(self.y)
        # self.x_norm = self.norm(self.x)

    def readtxt(self):
        arr = []
        data = open(self.file, 'r')
        for line in data.readlines():
            point = line.split(',')
            arr.append([float(point[i]) for i in range(len(point))])
        arr = np.append(np.ones([len(arr),1]),arr,1)
        return arr

    def norm(self, matrix):
        mat = matrix
        col_num = len(mat[0])
        row_num = len(mat)
        mu = np.array([np.average(mat[:,i]) for i in range(col_num)])
        size = np.array([max(mat[:,i])-min(mat[:,i]) for i in range(col_num)])
        for i in range(len(size)):
            if (size[i] > 0.00001):
                mat[:,i]=(mat[:,i]-mu[i])/size[i]
        return mat
```

My guess is that variable 'mat' is taken as the object 'matrix' (self.x passed into norm) in memory and is then overwritten?

Edit / question clarification: What's the best way to avoid overwriting existing data within a python class structure?

Comment: You could use `.copy()` or alternatively `import deepcopy` if this doesn't work

Comment: "within a python class structure?": the class has nothing to do with it. More the fact that assignment doesn't always copy things (lists and numpy arrays are referenced, not copied, when using `=`).

Answer (score 3):

In Python, anything beyond simple built-in types are passed to functions by reference, meaning that a function does not get a copy of an object, but rather the object itself:

```
def f(x):
   x[2] = 100

x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
f(x)
print(x)
# [1, 2, 100, 4]
```

This is also true of assignment operator: simply saying `y = x` or `mat = matrix` does not make a copy of the object, rather it creates a new name pointing to the same object:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = x
y[2] = 100
print(x)
# [1, 2, 100, 4]
```

If you really want a copy of a numpy array or any other object, you need to be explicit about it. One way to do this with numpy is to use the `.copy()` method:

```
x = np.arange(4)
y = x.copy()
y[2] = 100
print(y)
# [  0   1 100   3]
print(x)
# [0 1 2 3]
```

Whether or not you are operating within a class, this will hold.

Comment: Thanks, useful explanation